# Javascript regex to get src url between script tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to get name of the script from such a string:

```
var text = '<script src="scripts/044c7c5e.vendor.js"></script><script src="scripts/fa9f85fb.scripts.js"></script>'
```

I wanted to retrieve the second script name i.e. **fa9f85fb.scripts**. How can I achieve this using javascript regex?

I'm writing something like this:

```
text.match(new RegExp(/<script src="scripts\/[(.*?)]\.scripts\.js"><\/script>/), 'g')[0]
```

But its returning the whole string.

Comment: Or better: parse the HTML to DOM and access the `src` attribute. Browsers are great in parsing HTML. FYI, `RegExp` expects a string, not a regular expression.

Comment: text.match(new RegExp('<script src="scripts\/([^\.]+\.scripts)\.js"><\/script>', 'i'))[1]

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling for your reply but I'm using regex in a grunt task, so was not using the HTML parser in browser.

Comment: That's why context information is useful. But even node has HTML parsers.

Comment: Yes you are right @FelixKling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern grabbing is a bit off; `[(.*?)]` should instead be `(.*?)` simply:

```
/<script src="scripts\/(.*?)\.scripts\.js"><\/script>/g
```

will be the entire regex, no need to call the `RegExp` class constructor either. The matched string is stored at index `0`. The various segments are then stored from index `1` onwards.

```
text.match( /<script src="scripts\/(.*?)\.scripts\.js"><\/script>/g )[1]
```

Comment: I got the gist @hjpotter92 about my mistake and got it working from the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/\w+.scripts(?=.js)/` ?

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Your match pattern is a bit vague. I can simply use /fa9f85fb.scripts/ to match it.