# Load all <script> tags from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm hooking into a separate page (same domain) and pulling it into the current page using `$.load`, which would be fine, if I was doing it for the whole page, but I'm not, I'm just doing it for the JavaScript code in that page. I was wondering if it's possible to load all the script tags from said page into the current page?

I'm currently using the below code:

`var newMessageURL = $('#lnkCompose a').attr('href');`
`$('#hiddenScriptLoad').load(newMessageURL);`

Comment: Is that page is in same domain??

Comment: @Nikhil.Patel Yes it is, sorry I'll update my question

Comment: yes every one is doing in the same way other wise you have to call ajax request to that page and find all the script tag from response and need to load that script one by one in your page but if your url is not that much heavy loaded then this approach is easy and good.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382410/html-template-to-use-same-header-for-every-single-pages/33382741#33382741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is said page on the same domain or do you have access to it? You will run into trouble with the cross domain origin policy otherwise.
If you do have access, the only way is to parse the html using a regex statement or html parser and pull the scripts manually. 
This sounds like a very hacky approach though and I'm not really sure why you'd want to do this.

If you have access, get the page contents and then use the below to get the script tag sources.

```
text.match( /<script src="scripts\/(.*?)\.scripts\.js"><\/script>/g )
```

Credit [Javascript regex to get src url between script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198305/javascript-regex-to-get-src-url-between-script-tag)

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't specify in my question, but the script tags contain the code, not a reference to it. I'm doing it because I'm writing a client-side script that improves my college's ETrack system massively. See [here](https://gitlab.com/roconnor/ETrackCleanUp)

Comment: Oh I see you're using Tampermonkey, which makes life easier. Use document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].src to get the contents of the first script then. Map over it either to get all script sources.
I know you're using jQuery but always nice to use some native functions.

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't specify in my question, but the script tags contain the code, not a reference to it.

Comment: I meant to say .innerHTML

Comment: Ah OK thanks, that makes more sense now :-). From what I can tell though I would still need to pull in the whole page... It seems way too much, is it possible to just pull in the script tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newMessageURL = $('#lnkCompose a').attr('href');    
$('#hiddenScriptLoad').load(newMessageURL);
```

The above code will load all the contents you have in the second file and it will also import any javascript codes you have there. But the codes you'll have in second file will not work and wont get into action unless you call to them from first page using a function call or in any other manner.

If you just want to separate your js codings and html and have them in two separate files, it would be better to use PHP to import the second file into the first one and in this way, when the page is loaded in the client browser, it will render it as it was just a single file containing both contents. Ex..

```
<?php
    include("script_file.js"); 
?>
```

And also if you want get only the js part of the second file use something like this

```
<?php
    $Vdata = file_get_contents('path/to/YOUR/FILE.php');
    preg_match_all("'<script(.*?)</script>'si", $Vdata, $match);

    foreach($match[1] as $val)
    {
         echo $val;
    }

?>
```